# Create a bibliography/glossary-like structures in Latex

Tags: latex, bibliography, glossary

I'm making a software requirements document in Latex.

I wanted to make something 'somewhat' easy to use since more people will start to do the same in the company if this gets a good reception.

Using the `glossaries` package we can create structures like

```
\newglossaryentry{utc}
{
   name=UTC,
   description=
   {
      Coordinated Universal Time
   }
}
```

and then, by calling `\gls{utc}`, it gets compiled and the name field is presented.

(Somewhat like using bibliography)

I was thinking of making structures like this to represent a requirement.
That way, we could create a file with the requirements and then call them in the document.

Something like:

**Input:**

```
\newrequirement{
   type=Functional
   priority=high
   description={
      app must save the world
   }
   frame={
      detailed description on saving the world
   }
}
```

**Output:** by calling `\printrequirements`

```
Functional requirements:

        FR1: App must save the world
   Priority: High
      frame: detailed description on saving the world
      ------

        FR2: 
   Priority: 
      frame: 
      ...
```

---

I can't use the `glossaries` package because it's already in use for the actual glossary.

I've been looking for a way to create such structures with custom fields, so we could decide the print formatting later, but can't say I even know what to look for...

I've created some commands with `\newcommand` and `\newcommandx`, is this the way to create something like `\newglossaryentry`?

I'd appreciate some ideas?

P.S. Now that I wrote the question, I think the best example would be the `bibliography` package, since it also adds a counter to the entries

Comment: Have a look at biber https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/6505/comment-faire-une-base-de-donnees-de-textes-en-latex-facilement-accessible

Comment: Also have a look at https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111fischer.pdf